# Linux: reshare a samba share

Tags: linux, linux-networking, samba, fedora

I have two Linux boxes and a Mac.

1) Linux-1 is on an internal network. Linux-1 has a bunch of external hdd and running a samba server, smb-1, sharing files from these hdds.

2) Linux-2 has two net interfaces, one internal and one external. It mounts smb-1. It also runs samba server, smb-2 which tries to share with machines on external network.

3) Mac-OS wants to access the files and folders of smb-1 through smb-2 mount.

But it can't. It sees smb-2, and mounts it, but all it gets is the share point directory with no files. Is this setup possible ? Can I share the already shared samba server files ?

Thanks...

Comment: Is there some reason you can't accomplish this with routing? Re-exporting network filesystems is usually a VERY bad idea - in that it usually doesn't work. There are deprecated options that may allow this to work, but it will be ungodly slow.

Comment: Yes, sure, routing might be the other solution that I can explore. Any samba specific pointer or  do you have a pointer to the ungodly deprecated options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone in this situation and wants to find a solution can give this a try:

Masquerade the internal network on Linux-2. I am using a Fedora server with `eth1` on the internal network zone and `eth0` on public zone.

```
 firewall-cmd --zone=internal --change-interface=eth1 --permanent
 firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-masquerade --permanent
```

Port forward all the samba ports from Linux-2 to Linux-1. Linux-1 has IP: 10.10.100.50.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-forward-port=port=137:proto=tcp:toaddr=10.10.100.50 --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-forward-port=port=138:proto=tcp:toaddr=10.10.100.50 --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-forward-port=port=139:proto=tcp:toaddr=10.10.100.50 --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-forward-port=port=445:proto=tcp:toaddr=10.10.100.50 --permanent
```

With this much of work, you can connect any client on the external network using the IP of Linux-2 which is also connected to your external network.

For example on Mac OS X, use `Finder` and `Go` and then `Connect to Server` and then type the IP of Linux-2, i.e. `smb://192.168.200.101`

Answer (score 1):

While it may be possible, it certainly isn't advisable. You should really put Lunux-2 on the internal network, then put a router between that network and your external network. You can find some reasonable used Cisco gear for sale most anywhere online. Then set up a split horizon DNS config that will allow that Linux-2 box to be seen from both outside and inside. A bit more complex, yes. But much more secure and probably more reliable too!